# Possible to override resource name when using DependentUpon?

Tags: c#, embedded-resource

I like to organize my code when using [JetBrains Rider](https://www.jetbrains.com/rider/) by dropping files on other files to make a hierarchy, such as concrete implementations of interfaces, etc.

I now have a class that will use some resources, "EmbeddedResource", and these are JSON files. I want to split these JSON files by a category/topic to make them manageable, instead of having just one big file.

But, when I drop the embedded-resource files onto the class file that will use them, I get a compilation error.

Additionally, the name of the resource changed in the project. Apparently, making a embedded resource dependent upon a C# class file makes the name of the resource be the same as the filename of the C# class file, instead of the name of the file containing the embedded resource.

It's probably better to give an example of what I did.

Here's what I did to verify:

1. Create a new .NET Core 2.2 Console application (named ConsoleApp4)
2. Add one json file to the project, named `file1.json`
3. Right-click this file, properties, set it to EmbeddedResource compile action
4. Drop the following code into Program.Main, replacing the existing code:

   ```
   foreach (var name in typeof(Program).Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames())
       Console.WriteLine(name);
   ```
5. Run the program

This outputs:

```
ConsoleApp4.file1.json
```

as expected.

I then repeated step 2 and 3, getting `file2.json`, re-ran, and sure enough, now I have two resources named `file1` and `file2` with the same pattern as above.

Then I drag one of the json files on top of Program, so that Rider has this organization:

[image: Rider file organization]

If I now re-run the program I get this output:

```
ConsoleApp4.Program
ConsoleApp4.file2.json
```

The act of making the file dependent on Program changed the name of the resulting resource. If I drag the second json file on top of Program as well I get this compiler error when I try to rebuild:

> Resource identifier 'ConsoleApp4.Program' has already been used in this assembly

The project file now contains these lines:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <None Remove="file1.json" />
  <EmbeddedResource Include="file1.json">
    <DependentUpon>Program.cs</DependentUpon>
  </EmbeddedResource>
  <None Remove="file2.json" />
  <EmbeddedResource Include="file2.json">
    <DependentUpon>Program.cs</DependentUpon>
  </EmbeddedResource>
</ItemGroup>
```

My question is simply this:

> Is there a way for me to change the name of the embedded resource, when I make them dependent on another file, as I have done above? Is there something I can add to the project file that will override the name that is being used for the resulting resource?

There is no mention in the project file that the resource will now inherit the name of the file it is depending on, this is some form of convention used by the compiler.

Comment: Why oh why do I find the duplicates only *after* posting my questions. Oh well.